# How to redirect on activity just like app redirect internaly

Tags: java, appium, appium-android

I am new to Appium. I'm stuck at redirection between activities after the application is launched.

I use below code to start the activity but an activity is opening just like new popup windows. Is there any way to redirect between activities just like application does, without opening in new windows.

I learned little bit on internet that it could be possible with explicit intent, but I have no idea how to do that.

Basically, I would like to redirect to homeActivity which I use to launch app. So I could redirect to home no matter at which activity I am currently standing.

```
Activity activity = new Activity(capabilityProperties.getAppPackage(), capabilityProperties.getAppActivity());

driver.startActivity(activity);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's your question is little confused to me , but if your requirement says that you need to redirect to home page of your app , no matter what activity its showing. One possible solution is you can try to use processbuilder

with adb command .

First try with adb command , if its working you can use this processbuilder function to open activity

> adb shell am start -d <"Your activity name/splashActivity">

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("adb", "shell", "am", "start", "-d", "<"Your activity name/splashActivity>");
        try {
            Process pc = pb.start();
            pc.waitFor();
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            Log.info("Exception occured . Failed to open splash activity");
        }
```